# Rails: Make views editable by end-users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

Is there anyway I can make content in my Rails views editable by end-users? Such that they can make simple text changes on pages I permit them to without having me edit the HAML files myself?

Thoughts?

CLARIFICATION:

I know about CMS systems, and I don't think that's entirely what I want. I want to maintain programatic control over my views, but there are sections that I want the user to be able to edit directly (for instance, I still need to populate the page with products, shopping cart, database blog entries, etc., but I want the user to be able to edit the "About Us" page or the "Contact Us" page, or edit the header text of a product category page, or provide an updated translation of any of those pages).

I know I can put these sections in a database, but since it's just a bulk of straight text, something didn't feel right about that approach (couldn't make sense of how I'd organize that cleanly and efficiently).  Could I pull this stuff from text files? Formatted in Textile/Markdown? Would that be a feasible approach? Or is a database-based approach probably the way to go?

Comment: It seems you're talking about a cms as hgimenez suggested, but if you know about HAML files, I feel you should know about cms's.  This leads me to believe you are asking something else.  If so, can you please clarify?  Thanks.

Comment: this is a great question and ive always wondered if it is possible to pass along the awesomeness of HAML to the end-user who doesn't have a text editor that's going to do the indentation for them...i don't think there's a way to do this yet but hopefully someone below proves me wrong

Comment: I need the users to be able to edit the pages created around my ruby code logic; this site is also an ecommerce site (must pull and display data from a database on products and services offered) and be offered in many different languages, so everything needs to be localized. I would like the end users to be able to edit the "static" content around the stuff that's dynamically pulled from the database. Does that clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a CMS. Check out [BrowserCMS](http://www.browsercms.org/) and [RadiantCMS](http://radiantcms.org/).

In short, you need to extract out parts of the page that are editable, and store them *somewhere*, typically the DB. You can have users edit those parts of the page via your typical web forms. Extra points for ajax/in-place editing, but other than that there's not much magic to it. [This railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages) may also be useful if you don't need a full blown CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/). It's a pretty powerful templating language extracted from Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use one of the many CMS's ([BrowserCMS](http://browsercms.org) rocks) or use one of the I18n tools that give you an editor for your i18n files, and make sure all your text is pulled from a language file.