# End user can edit the view of a recored in some sort of editor - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm looking for something like an editor but instead of the user editing just a post or page the user can edit the default template layout or view layout for all pages associated to something.

I'll give an example to get my question across because i really don't know what it would be called.

Say for example you have categories. (people, animals, etc..)

Now imagine there is a category of people, each person in the category has the keys 'height', 'weight' and 'age' and each key has values assigned to them (height: 120 cm, weight: 80 pounds, age: 25)

I want the user to be able to edit the layout of the people page (page template or view that each person is displayed on) and be able to add in the keys they want to be displayed on the page. 
So say they add the keys ‘height’ and ‘weight’ it will only display the height and weight on every person page, plus whatever pre set text the user added in the template editor for the people pages to display.

I could probably find a good editor that can be customised and change it to my liking but there might already be gems out there made for this.

My question is, is there a gem for basically letting users set templates for record pages.

Even if there is something out there to change views for objects but the user cant set the keys on it, i'd still like to see it because I might be able to add the key/value functionality to it.

Hopefully you understand what I'm looking for.

**UPDATE**

Ok so i appears I'm after an editor that works with a template engine like liquid or one thats both an editor and template engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on building from scratch, it sounds like it could be done using `rails generate scaffold` this allows views/models/controllers to create pages for each of your categories.

Then you can use [Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to create associations between your categories.

You can also make different user roles by making a field called "Role" in your `Users` relation

Otherwise, there are also open-source software [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/) to manage content for your categories.

EDIT: After looking around I found a gem you can use to have end-users edit your own views, feel free to check out [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/).

Comment: Thanks but i all ready have the basic setup in place. Your answer wasn't really related to my question.

Comment: @user3234020 Hmm, your question sounds a bit vague, have you checked this question already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566393/rails-make-views-editable-by-end-users?rq=1

Comment: Yes i saw that post but i was asked 6 years ago.

Comment: @user3234020 Liquid is still used by the industry and the last update for it was a couple of days ago: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/commits/master

Comment: Thanks liquid looks alright, I need something like that but with an added editor or an editor gem that works well with liquid.